# Performing measures within the execution of a c++ code every t milliseconds

Tags: c++, c

Given a while loop and the function ordering as follows:

```
int k=0;
int total=100;
while(k<total){
   doSomething();
   if(approx. t milliseconds elapsed) { measure(); }
   ++k;
}
```

I want to perform 'measure' every t-th milliseconds. However, since 'doSomething' can be close to the t-th millisecond from the last execution, it is acceptable to perform the measure after approximately t milliseconds elapsed from the last measure. 
My question is: how could this be achieved?

One solution would be to set timer to zero, and measure it after every 'doSomething'. When it is withing the acceptable range, I perform measures, and reset. However, I'm not which c++ function I should use for such a task. As I can see, there are certain functions, but the debate on which one is the most appropriate is outside of my understanding. Note that some of the functions actually take into account the time taken by some other processes, but I want my timer to only measure the time of the execution of my c++ code (I hope that is clear). Another thing is the resolution of the measurements, as pointed out below. Suppose the medium option of those suggested.

Comment: Get the time before calling doSomething(), get the time after, make the difference and if t milliseconds elapsed measure it. What is doSomething() takes more than t?

Comment: platform specific high resolution timer could be used for getting the milliseconds elapsed. How long does `doSomething()` take? What kind of resolution on the milliseconds do you need, 1-2? 5-10? 50-100?

Comment: the title says "interrupting". do yo want to interrupt doSomething() to perform the measurement? that's something completely different.

Comment: It is pretty important to make a sampling profiler a separate process or thread so you can actually interrupt code execution.  Required operating system and tooling details are missing.  But a sampling profiler is a pretty standard tool, it would be a mistake to re-invent that wheel.

Comment: As I stated in the edit: to remove the need of the actual interruption, the measures can be performed after each function call. In other words, it is necessary to allow 'doSomething' to perform its task.

Comment: Have you got the `k` increment in the correct place?  As it stands you will get a non-deterministic number of samples based on the execution time of `doSomething()` if that time is negligible, then you will probably end up with no samples at all since `k` will increment to 100 before the measure period has elapsed even once.  If it is not negligible, then it will affect the accuracy of your measurement period in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High resolution timing is platform specific, and you have not specified in the question.  The standard library clock() function returns a count that increments at CLOCKS_PER_SEC per second.  On some platforms this may be fast enough to give you the resolution you need but you should check your system's tick rate since it is implementation defined.  However if you find it is high enough then:

```
#define SAMPLE_PERIOD_MS 100
#define SAMPLE_PERIOD_TICKS ((CLOCKS_PER_SEC * SAMPLE_PERIOD_MS) / 1000)

int k=0;
int total=100;
clock_t measure_time = clock() + SAMPLE_PERIOD_TICKS  ;
while(k<total)
{
   doSomething();
   if( clock() - measure_time > 0 )
   { 
        measure(); 
        measure_time += SAMPLE_PERIOD_TICKS ;
        ++k;
   }
}
```

You might replace clock() with some other high-resolution clock source if necessary.

However note a couple of issues.  This method is a "busy-loop"; unless either doSomething() or measure() yield the CPU, the process will take all the cpu cycles it can.  If this is the only code running on a target, that may not matter.  On the other hand is this is running on a general purpose OS such as Windows or Linux which are not real-time, the process may be pre-empted by other processes, and this may affect the accuracy of the sampling periodicity.  If you need accurate timing use of an RTOS and performing doSomething() and measure() in separate threads would be better.  Even in a GPOS that would be better.  For example a general pattern (using a made-up API in teh absence of any specification) would be:

```
int main()
{
    StartThread( measure_thread, HIGH_PRIORITY ) ;
    for(;;)
    {
        doSomething() ;
    }
}

void measure_thread()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        measure() ;
        sleep( SAMPLE_PERIOD_MS ) ;
    }
}
```

The code for `measure_thread()` is only accurate if `measure()` takes a negligible time to run.  If it takes significant time you may need to account for that.  If it is non-deterministic, you may even have to measure its execution time in order to subtract it the sleep period.

Comment: The answer accounts for most of the possible issues I might encounter. Note that I've already experienced some inconsistent results where dramatically asymptotically faster algorithm actually takes more time, as measured. This happens occasionally, but is inappropriate in an experimental setting with the purpose to demonstrate the superiority of one method. Anyway, the code will be subject to hundreds of samples, with different params., so the final result should be 'fair enough'.

Comment: It of course entirely depends what you are measuring and for what purpose, but sampling jitter may in some cases be critical.  In a closed loop control system for example jitter in both sampling and control could seriously affect stability.  Any situation where you are making real-time decisions on the measurement require minimisation of jitter relative to the sampling time.